# How to analyze the strings from a database table in a more efficient and better way based on a parameter?

Tags: javascript, typescript, architecture

I have two databases which are hooked to two different backend application servers. Both the servers talk to one single web application. Now, one can simply change a url parameter on the UI to choose which service to communicate with i.e., if you set `serverUrl='abc'`, it would point to `server A` with `database A`, and if you set `serverUrl='cde'`, it would point to `server B` with `database B`. I have workflow tests on the front end which are basically common for both the services. But the field names in the `db A` and `db B` are different. i.e., lets say if I have a field name called as "webid" in `db A`, the same field name is called as "`Webid`" in `db B` and similarly there are more like "`code`" in `db A` is "`CODE`" in `db B`. So, instead of duplicating my tests, I simply created a function, where I simply check based on the serverUrl, if it's `db A`, return "code" else return "`CODE`", and so on for all the field names in the database. So, in my tests, instead of simply creating the query with the normal `fieldname`, I pass in `checkField("code")` and it returns a string based on the condition (`serverUrl`) and executes the query.

The function is as follows:

```
function checkField(str: string) : string {
          let server = serverUrl === 'abc' ? true : false;
           switch (args[0].toLowerCase()) {
            case 'code':
                return serverUrl ? 'code' : 'CODE';
            case 'webid':
                return serverUrl ? 'webid' : 'Webid';
            case 'pkid':
                return serverUrl ? 'pkid' : 'PkId';
            case 'barcode':
                return serverUrl ? 'barcode' : 'Barcode';
            case 'price':
                return serverUrl ? 'price' : 'Price';
            case 'bestbefore':
                return serverUrl ? 'bestbefore' : 'BestBefore';
            case 'produce':
                return serverUrl ? 'produce' : 'Produce';
            case 'sales':
                return serverUrl ? 'sales' : 'Sales';
            case 'marketid':
                return serverUrl ? "marketid" : "MarketId";
            case 'regdate':
                return serverUrl ? "regdate" : "Regdate"; //and more fields
            default:
                return args[0]; 

}
```

So, I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this kind of comparison. Can we use static code analyzers here in anyway?[I am not really sure what they are] Any insights or pointers would be great. 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you mean the boolean `server` in each of those ternaries, not the `serverUrl`? Also what's `args[0]`, did you mean `str`?

Comment: I might use a hardcoded object so that you can use notation like `fieldnames['serverA']['bestbefore']`, etc. Feels like less work for a simple lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insight would be that when `serverUrl` is truthy, you don't need the `switch` at all - you always return the same value that was switched upon. So don't do the test in every switch `case`, but do it once before that:

```
function checkField(str: string) : string {
    if (serverUrl === 'abc')
        return str.toLowerCase();
    else
        switch (str.toLowerCase()) {
            case 'code': return 'CODE';
            case 'webid': return 'Webid';
            case 'pkid': return 'PkId';
            case 'barcode': return 'Barcode';
            case 'price': return 'Price';
            case 'bestbefore': return 'BestBefore';
            case 'produce': return 'Produce';
            case 'sales': return 'Sales';
            case 'marketid': return "MarketId";
            case 'regdate': return "Regdate";
            //and more fields
            default: return str;
        }
}
```

Instead of the `switch` statement, you can also use an object literal or a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as a lookup table.

Comment: I noticed that I have some cases where the `case` string doesn't match either of the values. i.e., `case 'mode': return serverUrl ? 'x' : 'y'`. How can I handle such cases? At this point, the implementation of simple map fails. Please help. I have no clue if I could do it in a different way other than hardcoding the values. I actually do not want to use a `checkField()` method. Do you think, without implementing the method, I can do it in any other way?

Comment: In that case I'd use two separate maps/switch statements, one for `serverUrl` being true and one for not.

Comment: "*I actually do not want to use a checkField() method.*" - wat? This whole question is only about that method. I don't think it's possible to go without maintaining a mapping between your application names, the database1 names, and the database2 names. You might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) though, with more details about those databases and the applications accessing it, possibly also at [dba.SE].

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing a bit from @Bergi's answer, I would create a mapping object to make it a little cleaner.  E.g.:

```
function checkField(str: string) : string {
    //create a mapping
    var myMapping = {
         'code'   : 'CODE',
         'webid'  : 'Webid',
         'pkid'   : 'PkId',
         'barcode': 'Barcode',
         //and more fields
    }

    if (serverUrl === 'abc') {
        return str.toLowerCase();
    } else {
        return myMapping[str.toLowerCase()] || str;
    }
}
```

This keeps the logic a little more separate from the mapping, so it feels cleaner to me.  But that's a personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the values in a map.

```
function checkField(String str) {
    let map = new Map([["code", "CODE"], ["webid", "Webid"]]);
    if (serverUrl === 'abc')
        return str.toLowerCase();
    else    
        return map[str]
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to use `map.get(str);`?